# Loading HTML file content in a Vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm having troubles loading the content of an HTML file in a Vue component. Basically i have a Django backend that generates an HTML file using Bokeh and a library called backtesting.py. My frontend is using Nuxt/Vue, so i can't just load the HTML on the page dynamically.

Here is what the HTML file looks like (it was too long to post here): https://controlc.com/aad9cb7f

The content of that file should be loaded in a basic component:

```
<template>
  
  <div>
    <h1>Some content here</h1>
  </div>

</template>


<script>


export default {
    components: {

    },
    data() {
        return {
      
        }
    },

    mounted() {      
    },
    methods: {

    }
}
</script>
```

The problem is that i really don't know how to do that. If i just copy and paste the content in the vue component, i'll get a lot of error due to the fact that i'm using a `<script>` tag in a component. The only thing i managed to do was to load the BokehJS CDN in my `index.html` file, but even after that i'll get a `Bokeh is undefined` error in the component.

What can i do to accomplish this? Any kind of advice is appreciated

Comment: You can check this video and  the links in the description https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J037aiMGGAw

Comment: I don't know much about nuxt, but how would you be accessing this HTML? Would it be a URL endpoint? Sounds like it would be a Django endpoint, but just want to make sure.

Also, what level of _reactivity_ are you looking for from the Vue component?

Comment: How to access the HTML is what i'm trying to understand; my original attempt was to just copy and paste the content in the vue component, but i got any kind of error like 'Bokeh was not found', Vue not being able to load <script> tags..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the simplest way is to make your HTML available at the URL of your choice, on your server (regardless of Vue).

Then, in your app, use an `<iframe>` and point its `src` to that html. Here's an example, using [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-flower-1gk6z?file=/index.html), where I placed what you posted into the `index.html`. Below you can see it working with both [`<iframe>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) and [`<object>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/object) tags:

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = false;

new Vue({
  'el': '#app'
})
```

```css
body  {
  margin: 0;
}
h1, h3 {padding-left: 1rem;}
object, iframe {
  border: none;
  height: 800px;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 125px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h1>This content is placed in Vue</h1>
  <h3>Vue doesn't really care.</h3>
  <iframe src="https://1gk6z.csb.app/"></iframe>

  <h1><code>&lt;object></code> works, too:</h1>
  <object type="text/html" data="https://1gk6z.csb.app/"></object>
  
</div>
```

Note: if the domain serving the graph and the one displaying it differ, you'll need server-side configuration to allow the embed (most domains have it turned off by default).

Comment: Thank you a lot! I thought about using the iframe, it looks like a good solution for now, but the only downside i'm seeing is what if the html file needs some reactivity like a form or anything like that? Also, since i'm using the iframe, does it mean that i'm going to have to store the html on the server and then point to the file from the vue app?

Comment: You don't need to store the HTML at all. You already have an endpoint that's generating the HTML+JS---the Django endpoint. Simply make the endpoint the `src` of the `<iframe>` and  you're good to go.

Comment: @Jack. i'm no expert in django or bokeh plot but, have you looked at [vue-bokeh](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-bokeh)? As a side-note, since you have control over both, communication between host and iframe is possible, it's just that it's more verbose, in case you want to send events.

Comment: @GuruPrasad, I never said it has to be stored. I said "make it available". It has to be provided as a response from that URL. For most developers, having an actual `.html` file is simpler to grasp but anything returning the HTML will do.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. I was responding to Jack022's comment: "Also, since i'm using the iframe, does it mean that i'm going to have to store the html on the server and then point to the file from the vue app"

Answer (score 4):

Tao's answer is spot on and is very similar to how I've solved this issue for myself in the past.

However, I'd like to throw in an alternative iframe approach that could work in case reactivity is important. Here's a [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-pine-dit2z?file=/src/components/Bokeh.vue)

The only difference is that this approach loads the code/HTML via XHR and writes it manually into the iframe. Using this approach, you should be able to add some reactivity if necessary.

```js
<script>
export default {
  components: {},
  data() {
    return {};
  },
  async mounted() {
    this.initialize();
  },
  methods: {
    async initialize() {
      const html = await this.loadHTML();
      const doc = this.htmlToDocument(html);
      this.updateIframe(doc);
    },
    async loadHTML() {
      const response = await fetch("/plot");
      const text = await response.text();
      return text;
    },
    htmlToDocument(html) {
      const parser = new DOMParser();
      const doc = parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");
      return doc;
    },
    updateIframe(doc) {
      const iframe = this.$refs.frame;
      const iframeDocument = iframe.contentWindow.document;
      iframeDocument.open();
      iframeDocument.write(doc.documentElement.innerHTML);
      iframeDocument.close();
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

In the codesandbox, I've thrown in two additional methods to give you an example of how reactivity can work with this approach:

```js
    modify() {
      if (this.orig) {
        // Only for the purpose of this example.
        // It's already been modified. Just short-circuit so we don't overwrite it
        return;
      }
      const bokehDoc = this.$refs.frame.contentWindow.Bokeh.documents[0];
      // Get access to the data..not sure if there's a better/proper way
      const models = [...bokehDoc._all_models.values()];
      const modelWithData = models.find((x) => x.data);
      const { data } = modelWithData;
      const idx = Math.floor(data.Close.length / 2);
      // Store old data so we can reset it
      this.orig = data.Close[idx];
      data.Close[Math.floor(data.Close.length / 2)] = 0;
      modelWithData.change.emit();
    },
    reset() {
      if (!this.orig) {
        return;
      }
      const bokehDoc = this.$refs.frame.contentWindow.Bokeh.documents[0];
      // Get access to the data..not sure if there's a better/proper way
      const models = [...bokehDoc._all_models.values()];
      const modelWithData = models.find((x) => x.data);
      const { data } = modelWithData;
      const idx = Math.floor(data.Close.length / 2);
      data.Close[idx] = this.orig;
      modelWithData.change.emit();
      delete this.orig;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Strategy:

1. insert and init bokeh in head tag of public/index.html
2. read file in a string via ajax/xhr and parse as dom tree
3. extract each needed dom element from the parsed tree
4. recreate and append each element

No iframe needed. `window.Bokeh` is directly accessible.

A skeletal example of reactivity is suggested through the method `logBkh` that logs the global Bokeh object when clicking on the graph

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div id="page-container" @click="logBkh"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
// loaded from filesystem for test purposes
import page from 'raw-loader!./assets/page.txt'

// parse as dom tree
const extDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(page, 'text/html');

export default {
  methods: {
    logBkh(){
      console.log(window.Bokeh)
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    const pageContainer = document.querySelector('#page-container')

    // generate and append root div
    const dv = document.createElement('div')
    const { attributes } = extDoc.querySelector('.bk-root')

    for(const attr in attributes) {
      dv.setAttribute(attributes[attr].name, attributes[attr].value)
    }
    pageContainer.append(dv)
    
    for(const _scrpt of extDoc.body.querySelectorAll('script')) {

      // generate and append each script
      const scrpt = document.createElement('script')

      for(const attr in _scrpt.attributes) {
        scrpt.setAttribute(
          _scrpt.attributes[attr].name,
          _scrpt.attributes[attr].value
        )
      }
      scrpt.innerHTML = _scrpt.innerHTML
      pageContainer.append(scrpt)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

result:

[image]